# HTML Form submit for Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, local-storage

I have a basic HTML form that takes input from the user about his age, gender, dob, email and contact number. I save it into the local storage as employeeData by making it an object in an array. [{},{},{}]. I also add a User_id that is calculated by a random function generator and display it using the Javascript. An example is mentioned below.

```
[
    {
        "U_Id": "1a9f1268-9c74-4cfb-971c-f595cb4a40e1",
        "Name": "dsgfdsfds",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Dob": "2022-02-04",
        "Email": "lsngldfsng@gmail.com",
        "Tel": "9958111111",
        "Hobbies": [
            "Coding"
        ]
    },
    {
        "U_Id": "d7e5b305-4604-4831-b168-96136a7b4ea5",
        "Name": "dghdghdhddh",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Dob": "2022-02-04",
        "Email": "lsngldfsn232g3@gmail.com",
        "Tel": "8989092345",
        "Hobbies": [
            "Coding",
            "Gaming"
        ]
    }
]
```

I create the object to store using `const formData = new FormData(form);`.

Now when I am fetching the data to display it back into the form, I am using the following function -

```
const empIndex = employeeData[index];
    const form = document.getElementById("form");

    for(let i=0;i<form.length;i++){
        console.log(form.elements[i])
        console.log(empIndex[keys[i]]);
        
        form.elements[i].value = empIndex[keys[i]];
    }
    const gender = empIndex.Gender;
    const hobbies = empIndex.Hobbies;
    form.elements[0].value = empIndex.Name;
```

But the issue is, the radio buttons are treated as 2 different entities and not as 1, which is why I have to individually set the name as `Name` and what happens is shown below-
[This is how the console looks after the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7e1v.png)

I need to know why does the HTML not deals the radio buttons as a group and a single entity, but rather makes it seperate entities, forcing me to input values with the loop into all the form elements, meanwhile I have created a group for a reason to be able to treat it as a single entity, just like an array. An array is a **group** of entities, but the HTML **radio button group** is not a group? Anyway to go about it?

```js
console.log("i am inside the script");

var incorrect = true;

function uuidv4() {
  return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, (c) =>
    (
      c ^
      (crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & (15 >> (c / 4)))
    ).toString(16)
  );
}

function namechecker(name) {
  if (name == "" || name.length < 5 || name.length > 45) {
    document.getElementById("namehidden").style.display = "contents";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("namehidden").style.display = "none";
    incorrect = false;
  }
}

function dobChecker(dob) {
  if (!dob) {
    document.getElementById("dobhidden").style.display = "contents";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dobhidden").style.display = "none";
    incorrect = false;
  }
}

function emailChecker(email) {
  const emailRegex =
    /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if (!(email && emailRegex.test(email))) {
    document.getElementById("emailhidden").style.display = "contents";
    incorrect = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("emailhidden").style.display = "none";
    incorrect = false;
  }
}

function phChecker(phone) {
  const phRegex = /^[6-9]\d{9}$/;
  if (!phRegex.test(phone)) {
    console.log("Phone number is incorrect");
    document.getElementById("telhidden").style.display = "contents";
    incorrect = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("telhidden").style.display = "none";
    incorrect = false;
  }
}

function incorrectForm(name, dob, email, tel) {
  console.log(incorrect);
  namechecker(name);
  dobChecker(dob);
  emailChecker(email);
  phChecker(tel);
  if (!incorrect) return false;
  else return true;
}

function Init(form) {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const name = formData.get("name");
  const dob = formData.get("dob");
  const gender = formData.get("gender");
  const email = formData.get("email");
  const tel = formData.get("tel");
  const markedCheckbox = document.getElementsByName("hobbies");
  const hobbies = [];
  for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      hobbies.push(checkbox.value);
    }
  }
  if (incorrectForm(name, dob, email, tel)) {
    console.log(
      "The form is incorrect. Kindly check and input correct entries."
    );
    alert("The Form is Incorrect. Kindly check the values and fill it correctly.")
  } else {
    return {
      U_Id: uuidv4(),
      Name: name,
      Gender: gender,
      Dob: dob,
      Email: email,
      Tel: tel,
      Hobbies: hobbies,
    };
  }
}

const but = document.getElementById("button");
console.log(but);
but.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("i clicked the button");
  const f = document.getElementById("form");
  const object = Init(f);
  if (object) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("employeeData")) {
      localStorage.setItem("employeeData", JSON.stringify([object]));
    } else {
      const existing = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("employeeData"));
      existing.push(object);
      localStorage.setItem("employeeData", JSON.stringify(existing));
    }
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("employeeData"));
  }
// calling another script from the button if the form is correct.
  if (!incorrect) {
    console.log("hi i am in basic!");

var tdStyle = "border:1px solid green;min-width:110px;";

const table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("style", "table-layout: fixed; width:max-content");

const tr = document.createElement("tr");
const employeeData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("employeeData"));

console.log(employeeData);

if (employeeData){
const keys = Object.keys(employeeData[0]);

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerText = keys[i];
  th.setAttribute("style", tdStyle);
  tr.appendChild(th);
}

const action = document.createElement("th");
action.innerText = "Actions";
action.setAttribute("style", tdStyle);
tr.appendChild(action);
const thead = document.createElement("thead");
thead.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(thead);

const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

function btnCreator(index) {
  const buttontd = document.createElement("td");
  const editBtn = document.createElement("button");
  editBtn.setAttribute("id" , "edit" + index);
  editBtn.innerText = "Edit";
  editBtn.setAttribute("style","margin-inline-end:10px");
  buttontd.setAttribute("style", tdStyle);
  const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
  delBtn.setAttribute("id", "delete" + index);
  delBtn.innerText = "Delete";
  editBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>editListener(index));
  buttontd.appendChild(editBtn);
  buttontd.appendChild(delBtn);
  return buttontd;
}

function editListener(index){
    const empIndex = employeeData[index];
    const form = document.getElementById("form");

    for(let i=0;i<form.length;i++){
        console.log(form.elements[i])
        console.log(empIndex[keys[i]]);
        
        form.elements[i].value = empIndex[keys[i]];
    }
    const gender = empIndex.Gender;
    const hobbies = empIndex.Hobbies;
    form.elements[0].value = empIndex.Name;
    document.getElementById("chkbx1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("chkbx2").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("chkbx3").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("rdbox1").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("rdbox2").checked = false;

    if (gender =="Female"){
        document.getElementById("rdbox1").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("rdbox2").checked = true;
    }

    hobbies.forEach((element)=>{
        switch (element){
            case "Gaming":
                document.getElementById("chkbx1").checked = true;
                break;
            case "Coding":
                document.getElementById("chkbx2").checked = true;
                break;
            case "Music":
                document.getElementById("chkbx3").checked = true;
                break;
            default:
            break;
                }
})
}

employeeData.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
  const tr2 = document.createElement("tr");
  for (let i in item) {
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerText = item[i];
    td.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid green; width:100%");
    tr2.appendChild(td);
  }
  tr2.appendChild(btnCreator(index));
  tbody.appendChild(tr2);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
});

const basicdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("basic")[0];

basicdiv.appendChild(table);}
else{

}
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.top-div{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.mid-div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1282cc;
    color: black;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    width: 75%;
}

.bot-div{
  background-color: white;
  border: solid thin #1282cc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

form{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.namelabel{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 22%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
  float: right;
  width: 73%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.required{
  color: red;
}


.dob ,.tel,.email{
  width: 100%;
}


.vertical{
  margin: 0 2.5% 0 0;
}

#button{
  background-color: #1282cc;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  border: #1282cc solid thin;
  border-radius: 4px ;
}

span.items{
  color:black;
  padding-left: 0;
}

div span{
    color: white;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding:15px;

}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 32px 12px 12px 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  }

  input[type=radio]{
      margin: 23px 12px 12px 0;
  }

  input[type=date] {
    margin: 20px 12px 12px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 25px;
  }

  input[type=email] {
    margin: 23px 12px 12px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 25px;
  }

  input[type=tel]{
    margin: 23px 12px 12px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 25px;
  }
  
  label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
.hidden{
  font-size: small;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border: blue 1px solid;
  }
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:840px) {
 
    .parent{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .col-75{
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 5%;
    }
    
    .col-25{
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0%;
      padding: 12px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    input[type=text] {
      margin: 10px 12px 12px 0;
    }

    input[type=email] {
      margin: 10px 12px 12px 0;
    }
  
    input[type=tel]{
      margin: 10px 12px 12px 0;
    }

    input[type=radio]{
      margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  }

  .mf{
    display: flex;
  }
  }

  /* Adding styling for basic table */

  .basic{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Employee Data</title>
  <script src="basic.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-div">
    <h2>Employee</h2>
    <div class="mid-div">
      <span>Add Employee</span>
      <div class="bot-div">
        <form action="" id="form">
          <div class="parent">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label class="namelabel"> Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="45" minlength="5" placeholder="Your Name" />
              <label class="hidden" id="namehidden">This field is required</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parent">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label> Gender:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75 mf">
              <div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="rdbox1" checked /><span class="items">Male</span>
              </div>
              <div><input type="radio" class="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="rdbox2"/><span class="items">Female</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parent">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label> Date of Birth:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="date" name="dob" class="dob" /><br>
              <label class="hidden visible" id="dobhidden">This field is required</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parent">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label> Email:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" class="email" />
              <br>
              <label class="hidden" id="emailhidden">This field is required</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parent">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label> Phone:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter phone" name="tel" class="tel" />
              <br>
              <label class="hidden" id="telhidden">This field is incorrect</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parent">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label class="padding"> Hobbies:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75 vertical" name="hobbies">
              <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="Gaming" id="chkbx1" /><span
                class="items">Gaming</span> <br>
              <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="Coding" id="chkbx2" /><span
                class="items">Coding</span> <br>
              <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="Music" id="chkbx3" /><span
                class="items">Music</span> <br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Basic</h2>
    <div class="mid-div">
      <span>Add Employee</span>
      <div class="bot-div basic">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Advanced</h2>
    <div class="mid-div">
      <span>Add Employee</span>
      <div class="bot-div">
        </div>
        </div>

  </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You're restricting your code. That's not the purpose of programming. If you need a function to perform a task over a string - such function should be Elements agnostic. Receive a string as argument and return a value instead.

Comment: Also your script has console errors

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const keys = Object.keys(employeeData[0]);
  const form = document.getElementsByName("form")[0];
  console.log("form in edit listener ", form);
  for (let i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    const formElement = document.forms[0].elements[i];
    if (formElement.type == "radio") {
      formElement.checked = formElement.value === emp.Gender;
      if (!formElement.checked) {
        document.forms[0].elements[i + 1].checked = true;
      }
      i += 1;
      continue;
    }
    if (formElement.type == "checkbox") {
      for (let j = 0; j < emp.Hobbies.length; j++) {
        if (!formElement.checked) {
          formElement.checked = formElement.value === emp.Hobbies[j];
        }
      }
    }
    if (formElement.type != ("checkbox" || "radio")) {
      form.elements[i].value = emp[keys[i]];
      if (formElement.type == "text") {
        formElement.value = emp.Name;
      }
    }
  }
```

This way I was able to check `formElement.checked = formElement.value === emp.Gender;` and set the value by using `formElement.type == "radio"`. I was unable to think about this and it finally hit me later when I was strolling around to find a solution. This seems such a small issue but the question still remains. Why is the button group **NOT A GROUP???**